# Matching query does not exist when update view is called in django

Tags: python, django, model

I have a custom user model from AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager. The user model is extended to a model called Employee. The employee model is related with(Foreignkey) two other model named WorkExperience and education. A single template form is designed with Employee, WorkExperience and Education modelform.

models.py:

```
    class Employee(models.Model):
        """
        Create employee attributes
        """
    
        employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        e_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    
        gender_choices = (
                        ('Male', 'Male'),
                        ('Female', 'Female'),
                        )
        ......
        @receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfile)
        def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
            if created:
                Employee.objects.create(employee_user=instance, email=instance.email)
            instance.employee.save()

class WorkExperience(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee previous work experiences
    """
    employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='we_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    previous_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    job_designation = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)

class Education(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee education background
    """
    employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='edu_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    institution_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    passing_year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    result = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

I have a CreateView of this three models. I have three modelform. I implemented CRUD using this modelforms. My problem is in UpdateView. When I call UpdateView an error is showing stating `WorkExperience matching query does not exist.`I think the query is not correct.

views.py:

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Update a created a employee
    """

    login_url = '/authentication/login/'
    template_name = 'employee/employee_update_form.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddModelForm
    work_form_class = WorkExperienceForm
    education_form_class = EducationForm
    context_object_name = 'employee'
    model = Employee
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()

    # Override default get method
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee_id = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee_id)
        education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee_id)

        form = self.form_class(instance=employee_id)
        work_form = self.work_form_class(prefix='work_form', instance=work_info)
        education_form = self.education_form_class(prefix='education_form',instance=education_info)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_form': work_form,
                                                    'education_form': education_form,
                                                    'supervisor_assigned': employee_id.supervisor_select
                                                    }
                                                )
    # Override default post method
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        employee_id = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
        work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=employee_id)
        education_info = Education.objects.get(employee=employee_id)

        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=employee_id)
        work_form = self.work_form_class(request.POST, prefix='work_form', instance=work_info)
        education_form = self.education_form_class(request.POST, prefix='education_form',instance=education_info)

        # Check form validation
        if form.is_valid() and work_form.is_valid() and education_form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            work = work_form.save(commit=False)
            education = education_form.save(commit=False)
            work.employee = instance
            education.employee = instance
            work.save()
            education.save()

            return redirect('employee:employee-list')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'work_form': work_form,
                                                    'education_form': education_form
                                                    }
                                                )
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('employee-list/', EmployeeListView.as_view(), name='employee-list'),
    path('employee-add/', EmployeeAddView.as_view(), name='employee-add'),
    path('employee-list/<int:id>/', EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='employee-detail'),
    path('employee-list/<int:id>/update/', EmployeeUpdateView.as_view(), name='employee-update'),
```

How can I modify my query? i think my query is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use foreign Key to use the employee id :

```
work_info = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee__id=employee_id)
```

I Hope it works fine

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Employee: Employee object (7)>.  getting this error. Actually I am passing object. Not number

Comment: Attach your Url and models py and it will help you to get answers